# Declaracion duplicada de Usercontrol en FormView

Tags: asp.net

Tengo un control de usuario que incluyo en una plantilla EditItemTemplate del formview, pero cuando agrego una segunda plantilla ItemTemplate y ubico una copia del control de usuario me da error de que ya existe una declaracion de ese control de usuario.

Esta es la declaracion del control en cada plantilla
' />

Este es el error
"BC30260: 'cbpais' ya se declaró como 'Protected WithEvents cbpais As controles_ucdropdownedit_ucdropdownedit_ascx' en class."

Answer (score 0):

Solicionado: asigno la plantilla ItemTemplate a las demas en el Init, asi tengo una sola plantilla del FormView para todo y evito duplicar los controles.